# variables changing value in fortran after calling random_seed

Tags: memory, fortran, random-seed

My problem is the following... I have an integer which changes value after calling the random seed function. The value is passed as a parameter and should be 20.
These are the relevant parts of the code:

```
 implicit none
 extrenal masres
 integer  :: i, j, k, n, nc, nr, irch, ncor, ierr, nfil21
```

...

```
 write(*,*) 'n = ', n
 del = 0.d+0
 del1 = 0.d+0
 call random_seed(size=n)
 write(*,*) 'n = ', n
```

And my output is:

```
 n =           20
 n =           33
```

I tried a workaround which failed too:

```
 write(*,*) 'n = ', n
 k = n
 del = 0.d+0
 del1 = 0.d+0
 call random_seed(size=k)
 write(*,*) 'k = ', k
 allocate(seed(n))
 call system_clock(COUNT=clock)
 if(info.eq.1) then
     seed = clock+37*[(1-i**2/1+i**2,i=1,n)]
 else
     seed = into+37*[(i+24)**2,i=1,n]
 endif
 call random_seed(put=seed)
```

What I get is:

```
 n =           20
 k =           33

 Fortran runtime error: Array size of PUT is too small.
```

This is obvious, as the random seed is apparently initialized with 33 instead of 20, so the allocated seed array will be too small.

I don't know if it matters, but I use the gfortran compiler.
Thank you in advance for your help. Tell me if I should post more code or upload the file.

Comment: Re-read the documentation for the `random_seed` routine, the argument `size` has intent `out`, ie it's value is assigned by the routine.  Your problems seem to stem from an expectation that the call assigns the value of `n` to the argument `set`; it doesn't, it does the opposite.

Comment: Yeah, indeed. Sorry. And thank you for answering anyway.